# How to show all posts of submenu which is a category

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to show all the posts of the submenu/category in my own theme. The submenu is a category. My menu looks like this:

```
- about (page)
- references (page)
--reference1 (subpage)
---test1 (submenu/category)
--reference2 (subpage)
---test2 (submenu/category)
```

I can get all the posts by using the ID of the category:

```
<?php
query_posts('cat=5');
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
the_content();
endwhile;
?>
```

But I need the category-ID dynamically (that the reason, why I define the category as submenu in my custom menu). But maybe there is an other way?!

When I am on the page reference1, I would like to show all the posts of the category test1. On the page reference2 I would like to show all the posts of the category test2. I can not figure out, how I can realize that. Any help?

Greetings and thanks in advance,
Yab86

Comment: You need to know how to show your posts in a page? or You need to know how to build that menu?

Comment: I have a custom menu. The submenu (test1 and test2) is a category. Now, I would like to show e.g. on the page reference1 all posts of the category which is a submenu at the same time.

Comment: But are you using the wp_nav_menu function to build your menu?

Comment: Yes, if I use wp_nav_menu It shows the whole navigation.

Comment: Ok, you know that inside of admin there is a section called Menu and you can customice the order of any item

Comment: Thanks Mauro. Yeah, I know that. Other question: How to display only the childmenu "test1" (3th level) on the page reference1 with wp_nav_menu?

Comment: ok, then sorry, i can't understand what you need.. oooww, i just saw the edit you made. Now any reason why you need to show your posts in a page?, why not use only categories?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like that:

```
<?php
$id = 5;
$args = array( 'category' => $id, 'post_type' =>  'post', 'order' => 'ASC', 'posts_per_page'=>-1, 'numberposts'=>-1 ); 
$postslist = get_posts( $args );   

    foreach ($postslist as $post) :  setup_postdata($post); ?>

       <?php the_title(); ?>
       <?php the_content(); ?>

    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

You will find further information on: 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts